# Trying to call some images via css on my 404 page but they are not displaying

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I'm using some css:

```
background: url('../images/gry_tile.gif');
```

At the moment my css is currently directly in the header of my 404.php with `<style type="text/css">`

My 404 page is alongside my index and other pages, while the images I want are in a folder called images.

The images are not displaying for some reason, they don't seem to be returning a 404 error either. Is there some apache .htaccess setting I'm missing somewhere that allow images, or are the file paths slightly different?

Answer (score 0):

Use this function :

```
 <?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>
```

ex: `background: url('<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/gry_tile.gif');`